# How to get name of directory (NOT subdirectory) and filename with PHP?

Tags: php, list, directory, subdirectory

I have following folder structure. I want to get names of only **directories** (NOT subdirectories) and **files**. How can I do that with PHP? Thank you.

```
Main Directory
 Directory1
  SubDirectory1
   File1
   File2
  SubDirectory2
   File3
   File4
 Directory2
  SubDirectory3
   File5
   File6
  SubDirectory4
   File7
   File8
```

Result should be something like that:

```
Directory: Directory1
File: File1
File: File2

Directory: Directory2
File: File3
File: File4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try DirectoryIterator,here is an example

```
$path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$it = new DirectoryIterator($path);
while($it->valid()){
    /*....*/
    echo $it->getPathname().'">'.$it->getBasename();
    $it->next();//i forgot this just now
}
```

Comment: i forget $it->next() just now. $it->next() means move forward to next DirectoryIterator item.

Comment: What should I write for $path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)); or I need to keep as its and move php file to the main directory? Do you think so or?

Comment: Both are ok.If you do not want to move php file to the main directory,use $path = dirname(dirname('/*your main directory path*/')),for example, $path = dirname(dirname('D:/Programs/'))

Answer (score 0):

```
function display_directory($path){
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("unable to open $path");
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)){
      if($file == "." || $file == "..")
        continue;
      if(is_dir($file))
        echo "directory: $file";
      else
        echo "file: $file";
    }
}
```

Comment: It just gives name of the directory not filenames. thanx

Comment: No, it gives names of directories AND filenames. Go back and look at line 8.